# Updating Jquery progressbar with codebehind for loop

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to implement this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_3

I tried to implement this first, but I don't know how to implement it. So tried to implement using jquery progressbar which I found some implementation examples online. I want the progress bar to be updated based on the code behind for loop.

I am new to front end development. Please help!

My aspx page:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="result"></div><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="Get Data" />


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $$("progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });

    $$('btnGetData').click(function () {
        var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetResult",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;                      
                var test = parseInt(data.d);
                $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", test);
                $("#result").text(msg.d);
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });


    function updateProgress() {
        var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
        if (value < 100) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value + 1);
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

CodeBehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static object GetResult()
{          
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    var Numbers = GetNumbers.Tables[0];
    var count = 0;

    foreach(int num in Numbers.Rows)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(GetData());
        count+1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have a look on this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-check-long-server-side-process-progress-in-real-time/

Comment: Hi Zaki, Thanks for the information, but I have to display a progress bar with updating status from code behind.